# Draw Before Scatter Without Problematic Offset Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

New to Kivy, not new to stack exchange or python.

So I have a scatter widget which I want to draw a circle on, then render text on top of. When I render the canvas after, the offset is good but the order is wrong, when I render the the canvas before, the order is good but the offset is wrong. How do I fix this?

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.properties import ListProperty

from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

import random

class Node(Scatter):
    pass

class main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Node()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().run()
```

#### main.kv

```
<Node>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200,200

    canvas.after: #offset good
    #canvas.before: #order good
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0.7,0,0.8
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        #---Debug---
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,0.1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Label:
        id: text
        text: 'foo'
        font_size: self.parent.size[0]/3
        color: 1,1,1,1
        size: self.parent.size
        #Debug
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,1,0,0.1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by rendering the canvas before, and removing the position information

```
canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0.7,0,0.8
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size
        #---Debug---
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,0.1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
```

This also has the added effect of being robust to scaling and rotation